# how this function processes json object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I need help to understand how the following function in nodejs processes json, i'am aware that the function receives a json body and an aes key to encrypt the fields:

```
function encryptAllValuesFromObject(body, key) {
    var bodyEnc = __assign({}, body);
    var parametersNames = Object.keys(body);
    parametersNames.forEach(function (parameter) {
        bodyEnc[parameter] = crypto_js_1.AES.encrypt(typeof (body[parameter]) !== 'string' ? JSON.stringify(body[parameter]) : body[parameter], key).toString();
    });
    return bodyEnc;
}
```

Assuming the function receives the following json, what should the output be like?

```
{
   "origin": {
      "typeId": "RUT",
      "numberId": "13501153-3",
      "accountId": "50010789193",
      "productId": "5",
      "subProductId": "5-202"
   },
   "destiny": {
      "typeId": "RUT",
      "numberId": "12870857-k",
      "name": "Prueba",
      "email": "prueba@gmail.com",
      "bankCode": "051",
      "bankDesc": "Banco Falabella",
      "accountId": "10012461337",
      "accountTypeId": "1",
      "accountDesc": "Cuenta Corriente"
       "isFavourite": true,
      "isNewContact": true,
      "saveContact": true
   },
   "subject": "Prueba Transferencia Mobile",
   "amount": "1",
   "softToken": "123456"
}
```

the output is supposed to be like this before being sent via post request:
[image]

Comment: "json objects"? JSON = JavaScript Object Notation, is a text representation of an object. When it isn't in text form, it is an object.

Comment: You are asking "an aes key to encrypt" but the function is called `decryptAllValuesFromObject` and are calling `decrypt`. So du you want to encrypt or decrypt? I'm confused.

Comment: corrected, sorry for the confusion

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The function shown merely replaces the value of each property in the object with the encrypted value of that property. If the property's value is not a string, it takes the stringified value of the property (the only place JSON is brought into this discussion) and encrypts that. So it should look much like what the picture you've provided looks like.

Comment: So, as @some mentioned in his first comment, the function expects an object, not a "json body", whatever that might be. You may wish to read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function expects an object (body) and a key.

```
function encryptAllValuesFromObject(body, key) {
```

`__assign` isn't a standard function, but I assume it's a shortcut to `Object.assign` which do a shallow copy of one or more objects into the first object. They copy the data from body into an empty object, so that they don't change data in the body object.

```
var bodyEnc = __assign({}, body);
```

`Object.keys` retrieves all the own keys from the body object and return them in an array, so it can be used to iterate over the keys. With "own keys" I mean the properties owned by the object, and not any keys from the prototype chain.

```
var parametersNames = Object.keys(body);
```

Since `parametersNames` is an array, they use `forEach` to iterate over the keys, and it calls the anonymous function for every key.

```
parametersNames.forEach(function (parameter) {
```

Now it is time to replace the value in `bodyEnc` for each paramter.

```
    bodyEnc[parameter] =
```

It calls the function to encrypt the data

```
    crypto_js_1.AES.encrypt(
```

It checks it the parameter is not a string.

```
    typeof (body[parameter]) !== 'string' ?
```

If it isn't a string, they call `JSON.stringify` to convert the object into a string (here you have JSON).

JSON.stringify(body[parameter]) :

If it is a string, it is supplied directly to the encrypt function

```
body[parameter]
```

As the second parameter to the encrypt function they supply the key
, key)

And convert the encrypted data to a string.

```
.toString();

});
```

And the they return the new object with the encrypted data.

```
  return bodyEnc;
}
```

The function can be simplified. There is no need to handle strings differently: Just call JSON.stingify on everything. It makes the decryption easier, since you no longer have to know if it was a string or object when encrypting.

Why not encrypt the whole object instead? Then you don't leak the keys, and it is easier to code.

Comment: I need to automate the function to do some tests in jmeter, I did not program the code